# Optimal image dimensions?

Tags: magento2

I'm creating my Magento 2, and I'm not sure what kind of images I have to use. What is the best extension? and what size should the image have to upload it?

Comment: There are couple of image optimizer module that you can use,
https://github.com/justbetter/magento2-image-optimizer
https://marketplace.magento.com/apptrian-image-optimizer.html

Comment: Yes but to upload the image, what is the optimal size to upload it and the format? or that does not matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload optimal size of 700px X 700px and Above, if it is good to have .png format

Comment: I read in the official documentation that the sizes are 470x470 and 1100x1100, so it would be best to upload images in PNG with size 700x700?